React radio input ternary operator not working
i'm trying to set a ternary operator on a radio input. I have several inputs so i use an array to place all the inputs. I'm doing this so that it can be set as soon as it arrives from a database.
<div className="flex items-center pl-3">
                  <label className="w-full py-3 ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ">
                    <input
                      id={item.id}
                      type={item.type}
                      value={item.value}
                      name={item.name}
                      required
                      {`${studio.studioType === item.value ? "checked" : ""}`}
                      className="w-4 h-4 text-orange-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-orange-400 focus:ring-2"
                    />
                    <span className="ml-2">{item.title}</span>
                  </label>
                </div>

This is the error i get:

and when i hover it says:

'...' expected.ts(1005)


It's not valid JSX syntax to surround an entire attribute with {...} to denote a computed value - you can only do that with an attribute value.
What you could do though is use object spread syntax, to spread an object that conditionally is either empty or contains the attribute you need.
Like this:
<input
  id={item.id}
  type={item.type}
  value={item.value}
  name={item.name}
  required
  {...(studio.studioType === item.value ? { checked: true } : {})}
  className="w-4 h-4 text-orange-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-orange-400 focus:ring-2"
/>

Actually, in JSX you don't set "boolean attributes" - those like checked which work by simply being present in the HTML, but with no actual value - the same way as in HTML, you give them a boolean value, and they are rendered when this is true but not when false. So this should work fine too:
<input
  id={item.id}
  type={item.type}
  value={item.value}
  name={item.name}
  required
  checked={studio.studioType === item.value}
  className="w-4 h-4 text-orange-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-orange-400 focus:ring-2"
/>

That looks quite a bit nicer - my only doubt about is that it makes it look like the checked prop is always here, when it doesn't acually make sense if the input isn't a checkbox or radio button. So it could be a little confusing to read. But it hopefully works fine based on your data.
